# How to replace a dynamic line in under 1 static line in pytho?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have the following text file:

```
This is a static line
This is a dynamic line
This is a dynamic line
This is a dynamic line
This is a dynamic line
This is a static line
This is a static line
```

I need to replace the first 4 lines under `This is a static line` with `New line`. Since the lines will always be dynamic how can I replace them? The text file obviously doesn't contact `This is a dynamic line` multiple times. This is what I have so far:

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    f = f.readlines()
    f.remove('This is a static line')
```

The `replace` method doesn't appear to work here. What can I do?

Comment: using that `.remove()` will only affect the `f` variable, You have to actually write it back to file after removing

Comment: @Matiiss Yup I print it out later on but this doesn't remove the lines under it. Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: use a loop, that should help

Answer (score 0):

You can read the lines into a list, use `list.index()` to find index of first `"This is a static line"` and then replace 4 lines after it:

```
new_line = "New line"

with open("input_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    lines = list(map(str.strip, f_in))

idx = lines.index("This is a static line")
lines[idx + 1 : idx + 5] = [new_line] * 4

with open("output_file.txt", "w") as f_out:
    print("\n".join(lines), file=f_out)
```